# I want to select the value from the dropdown

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am testing www.paytm.com

In that I have filled in the mobile number but I am not able to focus and select the mobile operator which is present in the dropdown just after the phone number section.

I want to select 'vodafone' as the value from the dropdown.

How to do that using webdriver

### Code I have written till now

`

```
public class MMT {

 public static void main (String[] args)
 {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/som/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://paytm.com");

driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-number")).sendKeys("9876543212");`
```

### What should be my next steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please Use `select.selectByValue("Vodafone");` **OR kindly post the HTML code** and go through this Link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver)

As per your comments below updated the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Test1 {
    public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            driver.get("http://www.paytm.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
               driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-number")).sendKeys("9876543212");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mobile-oprator-dd']/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[18]/a/span")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-amount")).sendKeys("100");
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-operator")));
            select.selectByValue("Vodafone");**//Here you wanted to select "Vodafone"**
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are new to selenium webdriver, please go through this link http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Can you please give me the whole command which I am supposed to write after the codes I have written?

Comment: Us this code please `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-number")).sendKeys("9876543212");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mobile-oprator-dd']/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[18]/a/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-amount")).sendKeys("100");
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-operator")));
select.selectByValue("Vodafone");`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your code but I am getting this error


Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='mobile-oprator-dd']/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[??18]/a/span because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id='mobile-oprator-dd']/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[??18]/a/span' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @Som Ghosh I just verified and it was working fine. Please recheck.

Comment: I suggest you, please go through the basic first. The link which I have provided you above.

Comment: Thank you
The xpath command worked but in selecting vodafone as the value but the select command didn't worked 

Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-operator")));
            select.selectByValue("Vodafone");

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways from which you can select the value from the drop-down:

**1) SelectByIndex**

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-operator")));
select.selectByValue(index of the record you want to select );
```

**2) SelectByValue**

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-operator")));
select.selectByValue(value of the record you want to select );
```

**3) SelectByVisibleText**

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mobile-operator")));
select.selectByValue(visible text of the record you want to select );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to use SelectByValue it is very easy to select the value from dropdown in case you want to select specified value as below.

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElementBy.xpath("//input[@data-reactid='184']")).SelectByValue("Airtel");
```

You should use exact name to select from the dropdown.